# Integridad referencial en MongoDb

Tags: mongoose, mongod

Una consulta, si por ejemplo se tienen 2 colecciones digamos, Auto

```
const Auto = Schema({

    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modelo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    marca: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Marca',
        required: true
    } 
    });
```

Marca

```
const Marca = Schema({

    nombre_Marca: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    });
```

Dentro de la colección de Auto *(Auto1,Auto2,etc)* tendrá como children una Marca seleccionable de los registros que se encuentren en Marca *(Chevrolet, Mitsubishi, etc)*, si se quisiera por ejemplo, borrar una marca que está contenida dentro de algún registro de la colección de Auto, ¿Cómo podría restringir que no se borre la marca si está dada de alta en algún registro? Esto como una especie de integridad referencial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si que puedes hacerlo, para ello debes usar un Middleware tipo `pre` sobre el esquema de marcas, en el cual vas a verificar la dependencia de los documentos de la colección de autos con la marca que intentas eliminar.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea restringir la eliminación de un documento de la colección de Marcas si el mismo tiene referencias desde la colección de Autos, con el fin de mantener la integridad referencial.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dados los modelos de la pregunta, una posible solución es crear una función [`Middleware`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) de tipo `pre` sobre el método `deleteOne` del objeto Query de Mongoose.

La función middleware puede escribirse de tipo `async` si se usa Mongoose v5.x o posterior.

Por ejemplo:

```js
MarcaSchema.pre('deleteOne', async function(next) {
  // obtenemos el documento que vamos a eliminar
  const marca = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery()).exec();
  // obtenemos la lista de autos que tienen una referencia a esta marca
  const carsOfThisMaker = await Auto.find({ marca: marca._id}).lean().exec();
  // si la lista de autos no está vacía
  if(carsOfThisMaker.length) {
    // devolvemos next con un argumento de error
    // lo cual previene que se elimine el documento
    return(next(new Error('Existen carros de este fabricante')));
  }
  // si la lista está vacía devolvemos next sin argumento
  // de esta forma se procede a eliminar el documento
  return next();
});
```

De esta forma, antes de eliminar el documento se verifica que no existan autos que tengan asignada su marca al campo `_id` del documento que vamos a eliminar.

Por ejemplo, el middleware anterior será ejecutado en la siguiente llamada:

```js
const deleted = await Marca.deleteOne({ nombre: 'Ferrari' }).exec();
```

Mostrando en consola lo siguiente:

```
Existen carros de este fabricante
```

Nota:

Los middlewares deben ser declarados antes que el modelo sea instanciado, por ejemplo, esta sería una forma de declarar este middleware en tu esquema de Marca:

**marca.model.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Auto = require('./auto.model.js');
const MarcaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre_Marca: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

// Ahora declaramos los middlewares
MarcaSchema.pre('deleteOne', async function(next) {
  const marca = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery()).exec();
  const carsOfThisMaker = await Auto.find({ marca: marca._id}).lean().exec();
  if(carsOfThisMaker.length) {
    return(next(new Error('Existen carros de este fabricante')));
  }
  return next();
});

// ahora si podemos instanciar el modelo
const Marca = mongoose.model('Marca', MarcaSchema);

module.exports = Marca;
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Lo pondré en práctica y cualquier duda me contacto por este medio. Saludos!